# Open a PDF file right after it was generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, web-applications, webforms

I want to open the PDF after the program generated it. I know it's already answered all over the internet but I can't find a satisfactory answer that will solve my problem. Here is my code when generating a PDF.

```
 protected void btnPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow rows = TraineeGrid.SelectedRow;
    Label varName = (Label)rows.FindControl("lbName");
    string name = varName.Text;
    Label varCourse = (Label)rows.FindControl("lbCourse");
    string course = varCourse.Text;
    Label varCertNum = (Label)rows.FindControl("lbCertNum");
    string certNumber = varCertNum.Text;

    Label varEndDate = (Label)rows.FindControl("lbEndDate");
    string endDate = varEndDate.Text;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
    string finalEDate = date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

    Label varStartDate = (Label)rows.FindControl("lbStartDate");
    string startDate = varStartDate.Text;
    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
    string finalSDate = date1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

    try
    {
        string inputCertificate = "D:\\Intern\\BASSWeb\\Certificates\\InitialCertificate.pdf";
        string outputCertificate = "D:\\Intern\\BASSWeb\\Certificates\\" + course + "_" + name + ".pdf";
        string newFileName = getNextFileName(outputCertificate);


        // open the reader
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputCertificate);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document();

        // open the writer
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputCertificate, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
        PdfContentByte cb = stamp.GetOverContent(1);
        var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

        Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 45, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(28f, 100f, 600f, 305f);
        Paragraph certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase(20, name, font));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();

        Font font2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 19, iTextSharp.text.Color.GRAY);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(28f, 100f, 600f, 370f);
        certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase("This is to certify that ", font2));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(28f, 100f, 500f, 277f);
        certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" has successfully completed the " + course + " at BASS Philippines RHQ", font2));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(28f, 100f, 500f, 210f);
        certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase("From: " + finalSDate + "", font2));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(28f, 100f, 500f, 186f);
        certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase("To: " + finalEDate + "", font2));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();

        Font font3 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 10, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(0f, 100f, 500f, 620f);
        certText = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Certificate Number: " + certNumber + "", font3));
        ct.AddElement(certText);
        ct.Go();

        stamp.Close();
        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
        document.Open();
        string script = "alert(\" A Certificate has been generated \");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(outputCertificate);
        Response.End();  }
```

I have also tried `Response.Redirect` but still does nothing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to close the Pdf, then just do `Process.Start(outputCertificate)`.

For that you need `using System.Diagnostics`

Also, I don't see the reason you are doing `document.Open();`, that surely has to be closed to use `Process.Start();`

Comment: It is clear based on the code the OP is implementing currently, that he originally believed (on my assumption here) that `document.Open()` was going to open the file.

Comment: @JMVillaflores Are you really sure this is what you want? According to your tags and parts of your code, you have a web application and the code you show executes on the server. In that case `Process.Start(outputCertificate)` opens the certificate on the server! I had the impression, though, that you wanted the certificate to open on client site. (If your development environment has both the server and the client on the same computer, this difference might not be obvious...)

Comment: Yes, that answer is what I really wanted.